# eclipseLink saving new objects in manyToOne relationship even when no Cascade.PERSIST

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have this situation

```
public class A {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_B_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private B testB;

}
```

I would think that no matter what changes are made to the property testB in class A, it would not be persisted. However, when I do the following

```
A testA = new A();
a.setTestB(new B());
save(testA);
```

eclipseLink tries to persist testB first before persisting testA. I would think that since the ManyToOne mapping on testB is not set to CascadeType.PERSIST and since insertable and updateable are false, any attempt to set a new instance of B on A would not work while saving A but I am seeing the contrary. Any idea what could be wrong? Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm testing code below against Eclipselink 2.2.1 and it throws an exception demanding `CascadeType.PERSIST` to be present:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object
was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: eclipselin
k.saving.neww.objects.in.manytoone.relationship.even.when.no.cascade.B@109f188a.
```

With Eclipselink 2.5.1 there is the same exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: test.B@6db66c18.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
```

```
A a = new A();
a.setTestB(new B());
em.persist(a);
```

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for checking. I am using eclipseLink 2.5.1. Is this a change in behavior? Do you have the full trace so I can check the class?

Comment: Post the whole implementation of A and B and how do you "save" it, because you pass the instance to some magic method `save`. Baseline is, just post more code.

Comment: Thanks for testing this out. It is harder for me to paste all of the methods that get called to persist since this is one small part of an Enterprise app. However, based on your finding, I created a small JPA project and attempted to do what I posted earlier and I got the stack trace that you did too. So in essence, my question is answered that JPA wants you to set Cascade.Type=PERSIST when you set new objects like this. Now I need to figure out why in my entity app, this STE is not shown but eclipseLink goes ahead and persists. Thanks much. I will report anything I find.

Comment: OK, I think I figured what is going on. In our app, it is not em.persist(a) that gets called but em.merge(a). Apparently the behavior is different for the two. The former throws a STE but the latter silently creates object B and then saves object A. I do not know if this is part of JPA specs, I am a noob but this is my observation.

Comment: Does anyone know though if this different behavior with merge is part of the eclipseLink specs or is this a bug? It sure sounds like a bug to me that the merge operation ignores the Cascade settings and does not warn the user about it.